# Perl regex to replace part of one string with a portion of another

Tags: regex, perl

I have a need in Perl to replace a section of one string with *most* of another. :-)  This needs be done for multiple pairs of strings.

For example, I need to replace

```
"/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration"
```

within

```
/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1
```

with

```
rfsn_clsnymigration
```

so that I end up with

```
/rfsn_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1
```

(without the leading "/root_vdm_2" part) ... but I am sufficiently sleep-deprived to have lost sight of how to accomplish this.

Help ?

Comment: Maybe `$string=~s/\/root_vdm_2\//\/rfsn_clsnymigration\//g;` haven't done perl before but looking at some docs looks like thatd be it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^\/root_vdm_2\/fs_clsnymigration
```

Substitute with:

```
\/rfsn_clsnymigration
```

example:

```
$string = "/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1";
$string=~s/^\/root_vdm_2\/fs_clsnymigration/\/rfsn_clsnymigration/;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
/rfsn_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1
```

**EDIT 1**

```
$string = "/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1/LISU,rfsn_clsnymigration
/root_vdm_2/fs_users/users/Marketing,rfsw_users
/root_vdm_3/fs_sandi/sandi_users,rfsw_sandi
/root_vdm_3/fs_pci/Analytics,rfsw_pci
/root_vdm_4/fs_camnt01/camnt01/AV,rfsw_camnt01
/root_vdm_1/fs_stcloud01/sfa,rfss_stcloud01
/root_vdm_3/fs_stcloud03/data4,rfss_stcloud03
/root_vdm_2/fs_stcloud02/depart1,rfss_stcloud02";
$string=~s/^\/root_vdm_.\/fs_[^\/]*/\/rfsn_clsnymigration/gm;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
/rfsn_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1/LISU,rfsn_clsnymigration
/rfsn_clsnymigration/users/Marketing,rfsw_users
/rfsn_clsnymigration/sandi_users,rfsw_sandi
/rfsn_clsnymigration/Analytics,rfsw_pci
/rfsn_clsnymigration/camnt01/AV,rfsw_camnt01
/rfsn_clsnymigration/sfa,rfss_stcloud01
/rfsn_clsnymigration/data4,rfss_stcloud03
/rfsn_clsnymigration/depart1,rfss_stcloud02
```

Comment: I would suggest that as you have `/` in the pattern, you'd be better off using something else as your regex delimiters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately this doesn't really help, because I need to parse _all_ of `/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration`  and replace it with `rfsn_clsnymigration` programatically.  Your example shows me a great way to substitute that one pair of strings, but the data changes from line to line (hence my comment about "multiple pairs of strings.")

Comment: @TyYoung can you post sufficient data along with your expected output?

Comment: @TyYoung it's all stored in one string?

Comment: @TyYoung ,I updated the answer,  check it out :), If it doesn't suit your requirement, post your expected output for above input :)

Comment: This new output should really be edited into the question. Comments aren't the place for it.

Comment: @Sobrique , I agree, I asked him to provide sufficient input and he posted it in comments :)

Comment: sorry guys, still trying to learn good netiquette within Stackoverflow. I've come up with a workable solution and as soon as I figure out how to post it coherently, I will.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($lhs, $rhs) = split(/,/, $_, 2);
    my @parts = split(/\//, $lhs);
    splice(@parts, 1, 2, $rhs);
    print join('/', @parts) . "\n";
}

__DATA__
/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1/LISU,rfsn_clsnymigration
/root_vdm_2/fs_users/users/Marketing,rfsw_users
/root_vdm_3/fs_sandi/sandi_users,rfsw_sandi
/root_vdm_3/fs_pci/Analytics,rfsw_pci
/root_vdm_4/fs_camnt01/camnt01/AV,rfsw_camnt01
/root_vdm_1/fs_stcloud01/sfa,rfss_stcloud01
/root_vdm_3/fs_stcloud03/data4,rfss_stcloud03
/root_vdm_2/fs_stcloud02/depart1,rfss_stcloud02
```

Answer (score -1):

My challenge was to replace *part* of $string1 with all of $string2, split on the commas.

```
/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1/LISU,rfsn_clsnymigration
/root_vdm_2/fs_users/users/Marketing,rfsw_users
/root_vdm_3/fs_sandi/sandi_users,rfsw_sandi
/root_vdm_3/fs_pci/Analytics,rfsw_pci
/root_vdm_4/fs_camnt01/camnt01/AV,rfsw_camnt01
/root_vdm_1/fs_stcloud01/sfa,rfss_stcloud01
/root_vdm_3/fs_stcloud03/data4,rfss_stcloud03
/root_vdm_2/fs_stcloud02/depart1,rfss_stcloud02
```

The difficulty I saw initially was how to replace `/root_vdm_2/fs_clsnymigration`  with `rfsn_clsnymigration`, and I allowed myself to think that a regexp was the best approach.

Although far less eloquent, this gets the job done:

```
foreach $line (@lines) {
        chop $line;
        ($orig,$replica) = split /\,/, $line;
        chop substr $orig, 0, 1;
        @pathparts = split /\//, $orig;
        $rootvdm = shift @pathparts;
        @pathparts[0] = $replica;
        $newpath = "/" . join ('/', @pathparts);
        print "     here's \$newpath:$newpath\n";
        }
```

... which yields something like this:

```
     here's $newpath:/rfsn_clsnymigration/CLSNYMIGRATION/NY_HQ_S1/LISU
     here's $newpath:/rfsw_users/users/Marketing
     here's $newpath:/rfsw_sandi/sandi_users
     here's $newpath:/rfsw_pci/Analytics
     here's $newpath:/rfsw_camnt01/camnt01/AV
     here's $newpath:/rfss_stcloud01/sfa
     here's $newpath:/rfss_stcloud03/data4
     here's $newpath:/rfss_stcloud02/depart1
```

Comment: `@pathparts[0]` should be `$pathparts[0]` since you're referring to a scalar.